# Hyperlink click action and ability to select and copy text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink, textbox

I'm working on a `WPF` application in `C#` and need the ability for users to click a hyperlink(execute the command) but also have the ability to select the text and copy it.

I searched for options but could not find anything that would help me.

Currently i have the following in my WPF XAML:

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
       <Hyperlink Command="{Binding OpenDefaultMailApplicationCommand}" >
       <TextBox Height="20" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="Blue"         BorderThickness="0">test@test.nl</TextBox>
   </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
```

What am i  doing wrong? The text is selectable only i don't have the ability to click on it to execute my command.

Comment: how you want to differentiate between a click to select and a click to execute ?

Comment: To be honest, i'm not sure about that. I was hoping to use the click for both but in the background check where the mouse is. If it is in front or at the end of the value, then the user should be able to select the text. But if the user is on the value and clicks it executes the command.

Comment: usually people will use ctrl+click for navigation ..

Comment: Normally they do, but the requirement is for just by click. Only if there is no otherway to do, then ctrl + click could be a possible way.

But would the above XAML still be valid then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a other approach for the problem.

By using a richtextbox and adding a hyperlink to that, a user is able to select the text but can also click it.

```
           <RichTextBox Name="rtbEmail" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Blue" BorderThickness="0" 
                                     Margin="3"/>
```

In the 'C#' usercontrol.cs i programmaticly set the hyperlink and add a click eventhandler to it.

```
                FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
            rtbEmail.Document = doc;
            rtbEmail.IsReadOnly = true;
            rtbEmail.IsDocumentEnabled = true;

            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            doc.Blocks.Add(para);

            Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
            link.IsEnabled = true;
            link.Inlines.Add(DataContext.EmailAddress);

            link.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.OpenEmailAppEvent);
            para.Inlines.Add(link);
```

Hopefully someone has use for this :). i did :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for similar req.

You need to have a textbox, which is non editable and is clickable. you can style it as a hyperlink by making in underlined and color changes etc.

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Text="test@test.nl"
                 Height="20"
                 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                 TextDecorations="Underline"
                 MouseMove="TextBox_MouseMove"
                 Foreground="Blue" />


private void TextBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CLicked");
        }
}


private void TextBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        var txtBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {
            txtBox.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        }
        else
            txtBox .Cursor = null;
}
```

Comment: why do you think this stinks? Is it because of the way the commands are used? What would your approach be?

Comment: i just don't like to use event handlers and manipulating a control for a trivial req. but may be as of now there is no alternative